# How to render italic/bold text using handlebars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache, handlebars.js

So here is the thing, I am using Handlebars to render the template on the page.

Now in the context js object, I have a paragraph, which should have few italic words,

For e.g:

```
var context = {
 "event":"This is event name <i>XYZ</i>" 
}
```

And the paragraph is rendered as,

```
 This is event name <i>XYZ</i>
```

Is there any way I can make/escape the font italic/bold in Handlebarsjs/Mustachejs ??

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9dp62g4/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the triple-stache

```
{{{thing_to_render_unescaped}}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9dp62g4/1/

Comment: but how do I let handlebars know that this is the part of the string I want to convert to italic/bold?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's html. See the forked fiddle in my answer

Comment: it throw an error in my actual code: "Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'"